# Capture Textbox value through a CheckBox asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, textbox

There is a Form which consists of Textbox which are activated or deactivated by a CheckBox ....

How can I capture the value that the user enters validating that the Check is marked?

[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFJMr.png)

My View:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function (){
            $("#idcheckproveedor").change(function(){
                var st = this.checked;
                if (st) {
                    $("#txtSearch").prop("disabled", false);
                }
                else {
                    $("#txtSearch").prop("disabled", true);
                }
                });
            });
    </script>

  <div class="form-group">
  <label>Proveedor</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="idcheckproveedor" checked="checked" />
  @Html.TextBox("searchTerm", null, new { @class = "form-control", id = "txtSearch" })
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give a name to your checkbox element as the values would  be posted as key value pair using the  `name` attribute  as key, so you can do following  in view:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="AllowSearch" id="idcheckproveedor" checked="checked" />
@Html.TextBox("searchTerm", null, new { @class = "form-control", id = "txtSearch" })
```

and in action you will have for checkbox  a parameter with name `AllowSearch` which will be of type `bool` to hold the either the checkbox was checked or  not when posted:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BuscarRecepcion(string searchTerm, bool AllowSearch_
{ 

    // validate here 

    if(AllwoSearch)
    {
       // do search
    }

    // else send back to view as validation failed.

}
```

Comment: I get the error: 
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'AllowSearch' of non-nullable type 'System.Boolean' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult BuscarRecepcion(System.String, System.Nullable`1[System.Int32], System.String, System.String, Boolean)' @Ehsan Sajjad

Comment: you would need your other required parameters too, i just showed you example to pass the checkbox status in it